# Message list float/arrow issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a list that will show messages. The image below is what I wish to achive. Check the codepen for how it looks as of now!:

[image]

As you can see apart of the ui jumps up as it it utilizing float. I can't set a fixed height on the avatar red area as the message area can vary in height (basically the whole message can vary in size). I've gotten it to work by removing the float on the text-container however I'm not able to lineup the green arrow then. Any ideas?

Hree is [codepen code](http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/mezLmJ?editors=110) for yous to fiddle with!

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="center">
        <ol id="holder" class="scroll" style="background:pink;">
            <li class="message">
              <div class="thumb-fav-container">
                <div class="thumb-fav-row">
                  <div class="thumb">
                  </div>
                  <div class="thumb-fav-num">
                  1000
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumb-fav-row">
                  <div class="fav">
                  </div>
                  <div class="thumb-fav-num">
                  0
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="message-avatar-container">
                  <div class="message-avatar">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                message
                <br>1
                <br>2
                <br>3
                <br>4
                <br>5
                <br>6
                <br>6
                <br>6
                <br>6
                <br>6
                <br>6
                <br>6
                <br>6
              </div>
              <div class="text-arrow">
              </div>
            </li>


                      <li class="message">
              <div class="thumb-fav-container">
                <div class="thumb-fav-row">
                  <div class="thumb">
                  </div>
                  <div class="thumb-fav-num">
                  1000
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumb-fav-row">
                  <div class="fav">
                  </div>
                  <div class="thumb-fav-num">
                  0
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="message-avatar-container">
                  <div class="message-avatar">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-container">
                message
                <br>1
                <br>2
                <br>3
                <br>4
              </div>
              <div class="text-arrow">
              </div>
            </li>


        </ol>
        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
/* Styles go here */

div.center
{
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 1000px;
  min-width:800px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 0em;

}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  left: 0em;
}

message {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.thumb-fav-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  width:70px;
  background: lime;
}

div.thumb-fav-row {
  height:20px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  background: silver;
}

div.thumb {
  float:left;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Thumbs_up_font_awesome.svg/512px-Thumbs_up_font_awesome.svg.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

div.fav {
  float: left;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Farm-Fresh_star.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

div.thumb-fav-num {
  float: left;
  margin-left:10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}

div.text-container {
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:700px;
  padding:20px;
  background: silver;
}

div.text-arrow {
  margin-top:20px;
  float:left;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid lime;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
}

div.message-avatar-container {
  float:right;
  padding:10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width:100px;
  height:70px;
  background: red;
}

div.message-avatar {
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-image:url('http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a04.png');
  background-size: contain; 
}
```

Comment: It completely unclear to me what you actually want to achieve. Please provide an image of how it is supposed to look like.

Comment: @connexo The green area on the left below the red area, is supposed to be on the left side. I thought it was clear enough. I'll update it.

Comment: @connexo Updated. I'm surprised you didn't know what I was meaning...

Comment: @KarlMorrison See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little mistake in your CSS:

Instead of:

```
message {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You should have:

```
.message {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    height: auto;
}
```

This yields the expected output ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zyxLej5f/)):

[image]

Comment: Why would you apply `width: 100%;` and `float: left;` on the same element?

Comment: @connexo Just quickly fixed his code. Didn't mind his other CSS (IMO he should fix his own logic)

Comment: @Jean-Paul Indeed my code is dirty, however need something quick atm. (I am to import the code and rewrite with sass later)

Comment: Thanks mate, knew it was something small I was missing!

Comment: @KarlMorrison Your colouring is also off. Check [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyxLej5f/) for the correct CSS.

Comment: @Jean-Paul Colouring? In which way? (I only colour like this to see the borders etc, most of the colours will disapier later!)

Comment: @KarlMorrison You should add `background:red` to `div.message-avatar` and not to `.message` to replicate the colour-scheme of your original question. See the demo from the comment above :)

Comment: @Jean-Paul Ahh I see now, indeed :)